# Evaluating $\int_0^x\frac{\sin(t)}{1+t^2}\mathrm dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I cannot seem to figure out how to solve the following problem: 
$$\int_0^x\frac{\sin(t)}{1+t^2}\mathrm dt$$

I have tried by using integration by parts.

I set $u = \sin(t)$, $v = \tan^{-1}(x)$ and  $dv = \dfrac{1}{1+t^2}dt$. Thus,

$$\int_0^x \dfrac{\sin(t)}{1+t^2}dt = \left[\sin(t)\cdot \tan^{-1}(t)\right]_0^x - \int_0^x \cos(t)\cdot \tan^{-1}(t)dt$$

Is this correct or not? I would like to get some hints, I am currently stuck.

Best regards

Comment: It is not an elementary integral! You can have an answer in terms of the sine and cosine integrals.

Comment: You can also use a power series expansion and integrate term by term since we assume the domain is closed and bounded.

Comment: yes, and even for unbounded domains... the improper integrals converge too

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large%
\int_{0}^{x}\frac{\sin\pars{t}}{1 + t^{2}}\,\dd t}
=\Im\int_{0}^{x}\frac{\sin\pars{t}}{t - \ic}\,\dd t
=\Im\int_{-\ic}^{x - \ic}\frac{\sin\pars{t + \ic}}{t}\,\dd t
\\[5mm]&=\Im\int_{-\ic}^{x - \ic}\frac{\sin\pars{t}\cosh\pars{1} + \cos\pars{t}\sinh\pars{1}\ic}{t}\,\dd t
\\[1cm]&=\cosh\pars{1}\bracks{\Im\int_{0}^{x - \ic}\frac{\sin\pars{t}}{t}\,\dd t
-\Im\int_{0}^{-\ic}\frac{\sin\pars{t}}{t}\,\dd t}
\\[5mm]&+\sinh\pars{1}\bracks{%
-\Re\int_{0}^{x - \ic}\frac{1 - \cos\pars{t}}{t}\,\dd t
+\Re\int_{0}^{-\ic}\frac{1 - \cos\pars{t}}{t}\,\dd t
+\Re\int_{-\ic}^{x - \ic}\frac{\dd t}{t}}
\\[1cm]&=\cosh\pars{1}\bracks{%
\Im\,{\rm Si}\pars{x - \ic} - \Im\,{\rm Si}\pars{-\ic}}
\\[5mm]&+\sinh\pars{1}\bracks{%
-\Re\,{\rm Cin}\pars{x - \ic} + \Re\,{\rm Cin}\pars{-\ic}
+\Re\ln\pars{1 + x\ic}}
\\[1cm]&=\color{#66f}{\large\cosh\pars{1}\bracks{%
\Im\,{\rm Si}\pars{x - \ic} - \Im\,{\rm Si}\pars{-\ic}}}
\\[5mm]&\color{#66f}{\large+\sinh\pars{1}\bracks{%
-\Re\,{\rm Cin}\pars{x - \ic} + \Re\,{\rm Cin}\pars{-\ic}}
+ \half\,\sinh\pars{1}\ln\pars{1 + x^{2}}}
\end{align}

> $\ds{\,{\rm Si}}$ and $\ds{\,{\rm Cin}}$ are the
>   [Sine and Cosine Integral Functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral#Sine_integral), respectively.

Answer (score 1):

i will use series expansion and find a recurrence relation.  first define
$$ J_k = \int_0^x t^{2k}\sin t \,dt, k = 0, 1, \dots $$

we have $J_0 = \int_0^x \sin \, dt = 1 - \cos x.$  now,

$\begin{align}
J_k &= \int_0^x t^{2k} \sin t \, dt = -t^{2k}\cos t|_0^x + \int_0^x 2k t^{2k-1} \cos t\, dt\\
&= 2kt^{2k-1}\sin t-t^{2k}\cos t|_0^x - 2k(2k-1)\int_0^x t^{2k-2} \sin t\, dt\\
&= 2kx^{2k-1}\sin x - x^{2k}\cos x -2k(2k-1)J_{k-1} = x^{2k-1}(2k\sin x - x\cos x) -2k(2k-1)J_{k-1}
\end{align}$

the recurrence relation is $$J_k = x^{2k-1}(2k\sin x - x\cos x) -2k(2k-1)J_{k-1}\,  , \, J_0 = 1 - \cos x\tag 1 $$

we can compute  $$J_1 = x(2\sin x - x\cos x) -2(1-\cos x),\\ J_2 = x^3(4\sin x - x \cos x )-12x(2\sin x - x \cos x)+24(1-\cos x), \dots$$

$$\int_0^x \frac{\sin t}{1 + t^2}\, dt = \int_0^x \sin t\left(1 -t^2 + t^4 + \dots\right) = J_0- J_1 + J_2 + \dots, \text{ for } -1  < x < 1.$$

Comment: Ok,that seems overly complicated to me. Wouldn't it be simpler just to use a straight up power series expansion and integrate term by term?

Comment: @Mathemagician1234, why don't you write up the easier method.

Comment: Don't mind if I do..............

Comment: The series for $\frac1{1+t^2}$ can only be used when $|x|\lt1$.

Comment: @robjohn, yes that is true. so i will include that constraint. robjohn, is the rest of my correct?

Comment: it looks okay, but the $J_k$ look hard to compute.

Answer (score 1):

The relevant power series expansions in the radii of convergence (0,x) are 
   $$\sin (x) = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^j}{(2j+1)!} x^{2j+1}$$
     $$ \frac{1}{1+{t^2}} = 1+x^2+x^4+\ldots= \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} {x^{2j}}$$

So now we multiply the power series and integrate term by term: 
     $$\frac{\sin(x)}{1+{t^2}}$$ = $ \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} {x^{2j}}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^j}{(2j+1)!} x^{2j+1}$ = $ \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{j+2}}{(2j+1)!} x^{4j+1}$

We obtained the last part by adding together like coeffecients as follows: 1 = $-1^{2}$ and $ \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} {x^{2j}}\cdot x^{2j+1}$= $ \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} {x^{4j+1}}$. So now we simply integrate term by term,which yields 
  $$\int_0^x \dfrac{\sin(t)}{1+t^2}dt =\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{j+2}}{(2j+1)!} \frac{x^{4j+2}}{(4j+2)!}$$

Comment: Many thanks,Brian!

Comment: That $\sum_{j=0}^{x}$ is suspect. What does it mean if $x$ is not a natural number?

Comment: (0,x) is the radii of convergence, obviously-we take each antiderivative term along this radii, but it's overall a convergent countably infinite sum. I rectified it. In light of Harry Peter's intimidating computation above,thought-I'm wondering now if it's correct. It sure LOOKS correct to me!

Comment: @Mathemagician1234 $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} {x^{2j}}=\frac{1}{1-x^2}$; Set $x=1$ then $\int_0^1 \dfrac{\sin(t)}{1+t^2}dt=0.499769...$ but $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{j+2}}{(2j+1)!} \frac{1^{4j+2}}{(4j+2)!}=0.321794$... . Maybe something is wrong?!

Answer (score 1):

$\int_0^x\dfrac{\sin(t)}{1+t^2}dt$

$=\int_0^x\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^nt^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!(t^2+1)}dt$

$=\int_0^x\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^nt^{2n}}{2(2n+1)!(t^2+1)}d(t^2+1)$

$=\int_0^x\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(t^2+1-1)^n}{2(2n+1)!(t^2+1)}d(t^2+1)$

$=\int_0^x\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^nC_k^n(-1)^{n-k}(t^2+1)^k}{2(2n+1)!(t^2+1)}d(t^2+1)$

$=\int_0^x\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^kn!(t^2+1)^{k-1}}{2(2n+1)!k!(n-k)!}d(t^2+1)$

$=\int_0^x\left(\dfrac{1}{2(t^2+1)}+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^kn!(t^2+1)^{k-1}}{2(2n+1)!k!(n-k)!}\right)d(t^2+1)$

$=\int_0^x\left(\dfrac{1}{2(t^2+1)}+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{1}{2(2n+1)!(t^2+1)}+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\dfrac{(-1)^kn!(t^2+1)^{k-1}}{2(2n+1)!k!(n-k)!}\right)d(t^2+1)$

$=\int_0^x\left(\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{1}{2(2n+1)!(t^2+1)}+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\dfrac{(-1)^kn!(t^2+1)^{k-1}}{2(2n+1)!k!(n-k)!}\right)d(t^2+1)$

$=\int_0^x\left(\dfrac{\sinh1}{2(t^2+1)}+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\dfrac{(-1)^kn!(t^2+1)^{k-1}}{2(2n+1)!k!(n-k)!}\right)d(t^2+1)$

$=\left[\dfrac{\sinh1\ln(t^2+1)}{2}+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\dfrac{(-1)^kn!(t^2+1)^k}{2(2n+1)!k!k(n-k)!}\right]_0^x$

$=\dfrac{\sinh1\ln(x^2+1)}{2}+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\dfrac{(-1)^kn!((x^2+1)^k-1)}{2(2n+1)!k!k(n-k)!}$

Comment: Uh-ok,that looks really arduous. I need to spend a few minutes carefully going through the computation. Is mine below correct?I'm pretty sure it is,although of course it's nowhere near as detailed as yours. Is the sum below equivalent?